# MS Access VBA/SQL check any of children

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

MS Access 2016

Goal, tag records based on child parameter; example:

```
Cat1    Cat2
 A       1
 A       2
 A       5
 B       3
 B       4
 B       1
 C       3
 C       2
 C       5
```

Goal, within Group By check to see if 3 exists and tag w/ "FBWT"; result:

```
Cat1    Cat2
 A      Other
 B      FBWT
 C      FBWT
```

I've thought about creating a dictionary based on Cat1 that updates the value based on iterating through Cat1/2 pairs then prints "Other" or "FBWT" but this will run on millions of records so I'm ideally looking for a function that I can run in a query that opperates the groupby on Cat1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select cat1,
       min(iif(cat2 = 3, 'FBWT' 'Other'))
from t
group by cat1;
```

This uses `MIN()` as a bit of a short-cut.  The strings are such that `'FBWT'` < `'Other'`.

A more formal way of doing this is more explicit:

```
select cat1,
       iif(sum(iif(cat2 = 3, 1, 0) > 0, 'FBWT', 'Other')
from t
group by cat1;
```

Comment: Why is FBWT < Other?

Comment: Is it length based or alphabetical?

Comment: I ended up just being able to do:
Select cat1, min(cat2) from t group by cat1;

Comment: @Schalton . . . Comparisons of strings are alphabetic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but more efficient:

```
Function IsFBwT(ByVal tblName As String, ByVal JVID As String)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    cTblStr = "SELECT [" & tblName & "].[FBwT IND] FROM [" & tblName & "] WHERE ((([" & tblName & "].[Journal Voucher ID])=" & Chr(34) & JVID & Chr(34) & "));"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(cTblStr)

    IsFBwT = "Other"
    rs.MoveNext
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs("FBwT IND").Value = "FBwT" Then
            IsFBwT = "FBwT"
            Exit Function
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is Standard SQL which means it may or may not work in Accessland:

```
UPDATE TargetTable t
   SET t.Cat2 = 'FBWT'
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                  FROM SourceTable s
                 WHERE s.Cat1 = t.Cat1
                       AND s.Cat2 = 3 );
```